# Using wget to download file to directory and email link/attachment to address

Tags: shell, email, cron, wget

I am using the following cron task:

```
wget -O ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/products-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S`.csv http://[site_URL]/product-report/csv
```

to grab a daily CSV of product sales. It is currently placing it in a files directory on the server and names it with a date stamp.

What I am looking to do is for it to also send an email with either an attachment to the file or a link to the file in the body, to a specific email address. I can't seem to find a way to do this. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**:

I've tried with the code suggested but it just outputted the trailing path to the file, not a proper download link. So I tried the following

```
echo "<a href="http://www.example.com' . $(ls -1t ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/* | head -1) . '">Download File</a>" | mail -s "Daily Products CSV Report" username@mail.com
```

But I get the echo printed in plain text. Closer..

**UPDATE**:

1) OK... So my first problem is that the timestamp I am trying to rename the file to doesn't work and the download fails. So I removed the timestamp (even though I would like it so it could make backups...) for now. The following code is my new line I am using to download the file. It should constantly download a new copy regardless of server timestamp. This is because the file is not actually generated at all until you visit that URL so there is no file to compare times with before wget tries to download it.

```
wget --timestamping -r -O files/csv_backups/products_csv/products.csv http://www.example.com/reports/product-report/csv
```

2) For the email, I removed the html and just left the following because for some reason the echo was rendering the html in plaintext which doesn't work. Why ever that is happening may be also why I couldn't use the **$(ls -1t * | head -1)** line at the end of the URL to grad the most recent file...

```
echo "http://www.example.com/files/csv_backups/products_csv/products.csv" | mail...
```

Comment: Do you have `mutt` installed?

Comment: No it doesn't appear so @JS웃

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have `mutt` installed then you can do something like:

```
echo "$(ls -1t ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/* | head -1)" | 
mail -s "subject line" email@address.com
```

This will give path to the file in subject body

The whole `echo $(ls -1t ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/* | head -1)` is because you will not know what the file name is since you are adding timestamp not datestamp. The `%H%M%S` will add hour minutes and seconds to the filename as well.

With the above command we assume the latest file in that directory will be the one downloaded recently.

Alternatively you can use `uuencode` which is part of `GNU sharutils`.

```
uuencode $(ls -1t ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/* | head -1) $(ls -1t ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/* | head -1) | 
mail -s "subject line" email@address.com
```

Comment: Alright, so in order for this to work properly, your code should be a different cron task then? I'm guessing that add yours to the end of the code I am running will not work, or will it? @JS웃

Comment: @TravisJohnston You can join both commands with `&&` so if the download is successful then it will run the next command.

Comment: Thanks for your help @JS웃 , I will test this out now. I tried the && but there seems to be a limit on how long the string can be in the cron task so I am going to make another task that runs 15mins after the download. I will test this in an hour after it runs to see if it works and if it does, ill mark your answer. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The first snippet you suggested sent an email, but placed the path to the file (not the full url) in the body. So I am going to try your other snippet with the uuencode to see if that works on the following hour. Wont be in until tomorrow to update. @JS웃

Comment: Ok so I can't get this to work. Your first snippet does send successfully but just places "/files/csv_backups/products_csv/products/csv" in the body. Not a full URL to grab the file. I also tried the uuencode example that you @JS웃 suggested but that just sends a blank email and no attachment.

Comment: @TravisJohnston If you want the URL in the email body then do `echo "http://[site_URL]/product-report/csv"` instead. It will send the URL from where you download the file since we cannot give URL that points to the linux box.

Comment: I was trying similar though I want to make sure the user can access the daily backup version that was saved with a timestamp on the server. It in a folder on the root of the site, so I can access it with a direct URL. Though need the echo to produce a proper link to the newest file, which is why I am trying to incorporate your head -1 code. JS웃

Comment: Trying ` echo "<a href="[site_URL]/files/csv_backups/products_csv/' . $(ls -1t * | head -1) . '">Download File</a>" ` To see if I can get it, since that's where its being stored. Though again just prints the entire code plaintext in the email

Comment: I marked your Answer. Though I still didn't get the final result that I am looking for, you got me to at least get an email sending somewhat  properly.

Comment: @TravisJohnston Sorry about that Travis. `uuencode` should have worked. Try this - `mail -s "subject line" email@address.com < $(ls -1t ~/files/csv_backups/products_csv/* | head -1)` This would display the content on the email body. Not sure if you would like to view it that way though.

Comment: Yeah I would prefer it to be a file, since its purpose will be to be imported into filemaker daily. It doesn't appear that my server has uuencode or mutt... and I don't have root access to install them so it doesn't appear I have much of a choice until I can get support to install both or one of those two. Thanks again. I will update this ticket if I get any further with this. @JS웃

Answer (score 1):

Heiner Steven wrote a good article about [writing scripts for sending files via email](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.html. He also wrote `sendfile` which uses the `metamail` package (available at the link above).

The other approach is to use `perl` ;-) (`man perlfaq9` covers e-mail) or to dust off of `uuencode`.

```
 uuencode Sales.cvs Sales.cvs | mail -s "Kaching"  listofmanagers@widgetsinc.com
```

NB: I think  all versions of `uuencode` require that you give the name of the attachment twice: once for the file to encode; and once for the name of the file for extraction from the message.  `uuencode` may also appear as `b64encode` on some BSD systems. You can Base64 encode with `uuencode` using the `-m` switch.

Comment: Thank you @G. Cito, I will take a look at what you suggested after I test out the second snippet provided above.

Comment: Good luck. Seems you have the HTTP fetching part worked out. BTW if you use `curl` instead of `wget` you can download and send mail with the same tool ;-) Cheers

Comment: I tried the uuencode options but that just sends a blank email.. I've looked into some other ways too but no go. (see my comment in the last post for some details) @G. Cito